# database vendor code:521

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Não estou conseguindo rodar essas query no sql 2008
fiz o teste no 2014 e deu certo
alguém poderia me ajuda? sou leigo de mais ao ponte de achar uma solução.

Segue as query:

```
SELECT D1_COD, D1_FORNECE, A2_NOME,
--1ª COMPRAS--
MIN(COMPRAS.D1_EMISSAO) AS '1ª COMPRA',

 (SELECT D1_VUNIT FROM SD1010 AS COMPRAS1
 WHERE COMPRAS1.D1_EMISSAO = (SELECT MIN(D1_EMISSAO) FROM SD1010 AS COMPRAS2
                    WHERE COMPRAS2.D1_COD =  COMPRAS.D1_COD
                    AND COMPRAS2.D1_FORNECE = COMPRAS.D1_FORNECE
                    AND COMPRAS2.D_E_L_E_T_ <> '*'
                    GROUP BY D1_COD)
 AND COMPRAS1.D_E_L_E_T_ <> '*'
 AND COMPRAS1.D1_FORNECE = COMPRAS.D1_FORNECE
 AND COMPRAS1.D1_COD = COMPRAS.D1_COD
  GROUP BY D1_COD, D1_VUNIT
 ) AS 'PRC_1ª_COMPRA',

--ULT  COMPRA--
MAX(COMPRAS.D1_EMISSAO) AS 'ULT COMPRA',

 (SELECT D1_VUNIT FROM SD1010 AS COMPRAS1
 WHERE COMPRAS1.D1_EMISSAO = (SELECT MAX(D1_EMISSAO) FROM SD1010 AS COMPRAS2
                    WHERE COMPRAS2.D1_COD =  COMPRAS.D1_COD
                    AND COMPRAS2.D1_FORNECE = COMPRAS.D1_FORNECE
                    AND COMPRAS2.D_E_L_E_T_ <> '*'
                    GROUP BY D1_COD)
 AND COMPRAS1.D_E_L_E_T_ <> '*'
 AND COMPRAS1.D1_FORNECE = COMPRAS.D1_FORNECE
 AND COMPRAS1.D1_COD = COMPRAS.D1_COD
  GROUP BY D1_COD, D1_VUNIT
 ) AS 'PRC_ULT_COMPRA'

FROM SD1010 AS COMPRAS

INNER JOIN SA2010 
ON  COMPRAS.D1_FORNECE = A2_COD
AND COMPRAS.D1_LOJA = A2_LOJA
--AND COMPRAS.D1_COD >= '' AND COMPRAS.D1_COD <= --'ZZZZZZ'
AND COMPRAS.D1_FORNECE >= '' AND COMPRAS.D1_FORNECE <= 'ZZZZZZ'
GROUP BY COMPRAS.D1_COD, COMPRAS.D1_FORNECE, A2_NOME

ORDER BY D1_COD, D1_FORNECE
```

---

a outra e essa msm coisa:

```
SELECT

--VENDAS--
 D2_COD, B1_DESC, D2_FILIAL, SUM(D2_QUANT) AS QUANT_VEND,
 MAX(D2_PRCVEN) AS PRECO_ULT_VENDA,
 B0_PRV1 AS PRECO_ATUAL,
 MAX(D2_EMISSAO) AS DATA_ULT_VENDA,
B1_GRUPO AS GRUPO,


  --DEVOLUCOES--
 (SELECT D1_QUANT FROM SD1010
 WHERE D1_FILIAL = D2_FILIAL
 AND D1_COD = D2_COD
-- AND D1_EMISSAO = D2_EMISSAO
 AND   D1_TIPO = 'D'
 AND   SD1010.D_E_L_E_T_ <> '*'
 GROUP BY D1_COD, D1_EMISSAO, D1_QUANT
 ) AS DEVOLUCOES,

 --ESTOQUE--
 (SELECT B2_QATU FROM SB2010 
 WHERE B2_FILIAL = D2_FILIAL 
 AND B2_COD = D2_COD
 AND SB2010.D_E_L_E_T_ <> '*'
 GROUP BY B2_FILIAL, B2_QATU
 ) AS ESTOQUE,

  (SELECT B2_CM1 FROM SB2010 
 WHERE B2_FILIAL = D2_FILIAL 
 AND B2_COD = D2_COD
 AND SB2010.D_E_L_E_T_ <> '*'
 GROUP BY B2_FILIAL, B2_CM1
 ) AS CUSTO

 FROM SD2010 AS VENDAS
INNER JOIN SB1010 AS PRODUTO
ON  D2_COD = B1_COD 
LEFT JOIN SB0010 AS PRECO
ON D2_COD = B0_COD
INNER JOIN SB2010 AS ESTOQUE
ON  D2_COD = B2_COD
AND D2_FILIAL = B2_FILIAL

AND VENDAS.D_E_L_E_T_ <> '*'
AND ESTOQUE.D_E_L_E_T_ <> '*'


GROUP BY D2_COD, B1_DESC, D2_FILIAL, B0_PRV1, B1_UPRC, B1_UCOM, B1_GRUPO
ORDER BY D2_COD, D2_FILIAL
```

Comment: Não é possível ajudar se não sabemos o que está acontecendo. Edite a questão com alguma mensagem de erro ou explicação do comportamento inesperado.

Comment: @Tulio: O problema pode ser na autenticação. Verifique o string de conexão etc. // Como está "rodando" o código? É no Crystal Reports? // Poste a mensagem de erro completa.

Comment: Neste código não tem nenhum comando especifico que possa está gerando erro, talvez falte alguma tabela, campo etc